# Can I Detect Hydroxyl Radicals Using Methylene Blue Spectrophotometry?

Tags: organic-chemistry, radicals, applied-chemistry

I am going to be pulsing radiation into a chamber containing a solution of water and both ferric and ferrous iron. The irradiation event should cause a Fenton reaction to ensue and I'd like to trap the radicals that are produced as a result. I do have a few questions, however, as I'm not super familiar with radical chemistry:

What amount of methylene blue should I add to make sure all radicals are accounted for?

How long is the methylene blue - OH radical complex stable for?

Will analysis in a spectrophotometer provide a crude quantitative measurement of the radicals?

Thank you for any advice and suggestions, I really appreciate it!